# CSS property for IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

What is the solution for rgba value and border radius value of 0.0 in IE8. 
The error i get is

> Value "rgba(250, 250, 250, .6)" is not supported. (8.0)

---

> Property "-webkit-border-radius" is not supported. (8.0)

Comment: `-moz-border-radius: 10px;`

Comment: IE8 does not support border-radius. Stop wasting your valuable time and tell your boss to live with square frigging corners in IE8.

Comment: So just ignore the error message i'm getting from text editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Option 2

http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius-demo.zip

Option 3

http://css3pie.com/

Option 4

http://www.netzgesta.de/corner/

Option 5

See this question

EDIT: Option 6

https://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/ - border-radius.
For rgba you can try create .png image with opacity and sat him as background

or try

```
.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```